# One layout pushes the other one off the screen

Tags: java, android, layout, user-interface

Currently i'm working one a small android project. I ran on a problem with layouts because I must create a user interface in Java. I have 2 layouts first is the LinearLayout with horizontal orientation and the other is a TableLayout. I set the width MATCH PARENT and height WRAP CONTENT for both of them but the first one pushes the other one off the screen and I want the first layout to push the other one under him.

The code looks like this:

```
    LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    LinearLayout hLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    hLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    hLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

    mainLayout.addView(hLayout);

    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);

    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    table.setLayoutParams(params);

    mainLayout.addView(table);
    setContentView(mainLayout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to add `hLayout` to anything so it isn't being pushed off the screen but never added to the content view. Try something like

```
mainLayout.addView(table);
mainLayout.addView(hLayout);
setContentView(mainLayout);
```

Also, since the width is `match_parent` and `LinearLayout` has a default `orientation` of horizontal, you will either need to change the `orientation` of the `mainLayout` to vertical or change the `width` to `wrap_content`.

And is there a reason you are doing it programmatically? Creating  `layout`s in xml is typically much easier.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't copy the sample code but i quickly wrote it and i forgot to add it, but I have it in the original code.

Comment: Ok, I see, but see my edit. I think the problem is with `orientation` and `width`

Comment: I have to make it programmatically because over time the UI is dynamically changing

Comment: Ok, but still I think the problem is with `orientation` and `width` unless I missed something. You have a `horizontal` `LinearLayout` as your main `ViewGroup` and its children have a `width` of `match_parent`...that is a problem

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with the orientation, I taught the orientation was vertical by defualt.